# Passing default global object to an external javascript module as 'this'

Tags: javascript, this

I want to know how to pass 'this' to an external module (script.js).
Currently 'this' passed to 'script.js' is undefined, but I want to find a way to pass the default global object instead. By the way, script.js is auto-generated by another library, so I can't change it in any ways. Please help.

index.html

```
<script src='./script.js' defer></script>
<script>
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            clearInterval(interval);

            (function (scope) {
                console.log('this inside of function')
                console.log(scope) //this prints 'global {frames: global, ..}
            })(this)  // <<<<< THIS works
        }
    }, 100);
</script>
```

script.js

```
(function (scope) {
    console.log('this inside of script.js')
    console.log(scope)    /// this prints 'undefined'
})(this)   // << THIS is undefined.
```

Comment: You can't pass it using an IIFE. You'll have to define a function (that doesn't immediately execute) and pass it to that.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the IIFE part because it's autogenerated by a 3rd party library. Btw, since this script tag is in the browser, I don't understand why 'this' would be undefined to begin with. Apparently, the library expects 'this' to represent the 'window' object.  Any ideas?

Comment: Nope. It's the `window` object in my testing: https://plnkr.co/edit/itmyE5k8BsPTVMmkR0rT?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I see how your test code works fine. The only thing my environment is different is that my index.html is being invoked by Electron as a renderer process, although I don't know why/whether it makes a difference. Thank you again.

Comment: Ah, Electron does make a difference; there are a number of gotchas there (from what little I've seen on SO questions anyway). You may wish to add the tag for `electron` to your question and perhaps update your question to include that fact. An expert in Electron may see the question and know the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have a separate question open more specific to Electron. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907735/reference-this-is-undefined-in-electron-apps-index-html